# Date in sql database

Tags: sql, localdb

i want to access date from my table and i only want only particular dates to display (for eg: date=1) .

Is there any way to access date,month and year individually from date format?
please help

Comment: Unfortunately some dbms products have their own ways to handle dates. Which dbms are you using? ANSI SQL way do get day of month part is EXTRACT(DAY FROM column)

Comment: Are you talking about MONTH(Getdate()) , YEAR(GetDate()) etc?

Comment: @jarlh I'm new to using dbms, i dont exactly know but its sql localdb. please help  and thank you very much for ur reply

Comment: @HolmesIV i stored dates in my table and for eg: i want to access only dates having month october then how to do it? and thank you for replying

Comment: Maybe some code showing the date format that use to insert dates into your database. The database RDBMS you are using such as 'mysql',  'ms sql server' or something else, would help us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avinash is this what you are looking for ?

```
select MONTH('10/15/1981') --10
select DAY('10/15/1981') --15
select YEAR('10/15/1981') --1981

Select Dates
from tablename
Where MONTH(Dates) = 10
```

Comment: This will work in some databases, but not all.  Unfortunately the OP didn't really specify which type of database this query should be ran against, so this may not work.

Comment: this is what i was looking for i will implement and chk  it ty